# iOS Struct Codable and filter?

Tags: arrays, swift, nspredicate

I want to search for a particular U.S. President by startYear, and I attempted to use filter in Swift 4. I could not get it to work. I am using the Codable protocol on purpose.

```
struct USPresidents: Codable {
    let FName: String
    let LName: String
    let startYear: Int
    let endYear: Int
}

let widroww = USPresidents(FName: "Widrow", LName: "Wilson", startYear: 1913, endYear: 1921)
let fdr = USPresidents(FName: "Frankly", LName: "Roosevelt", startYear: 1933, endYear: 1945)
let jkf = USPresidents(FName: "John", LName: "Kennedy", startYear: 1961, endYear: 1963)
let dde = USPresidents(FName: "Dwight", LName: "Eisenhowser", startYear: 1953, endYear: 1961)
let anj = USPresidents(FName: "Andrew", LName: "Jackson", startYear: 1865, endYear: 1869)
let gew = USPresidents(FName: "George", LName: "Washington", startYear: 1789, endYear: 1796)

var allPresidents = [USPresidents]()
allPresidents.append(contentsOf: [fdr,jkf,dde,anj,gew])


let searchFor = [1953]
let result = allPresidents.filter {  $0.startYear.contains({ $0.searchFor.contains($0) })
print("\n\nPresident in 1953 was:  = \(result)\n\n")
```

Comment: `startYear.contains` startYear is an `Int`. It doesn't have a `contains` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your filter to see if `searchFor` contains the `startYear`.

```
let result = allPresidents.filter { searchFor.contains($0.startYear) }
```

Comment: All of the results posted here produces a result, but this solution exactly answers my question. Thus, I am marking it as correct, albeit, the other solutions also work.

Answer (score 1):

Use ranges for the years instead of separate Ints, and then you can do a contains check:

```
struct USPresident: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let startYear: Int
    let endYear: Int

    var yearsInOffice: CountableClosedRange<Int> {
        return startYear...endYear
    }
}

let allPresidents = [
    USPresident(firstName: "Widrow",    lastName: "Wilson",         startYear: 1913, endYear: 1921),
    USPresident(firstName: "Frankly",   lastName: "Roosevelt",      startYear: 1933, endYear: 1945),
    USPresident(firstName: "John",      lastName: "Kennedy",        startYear: 1961, endYear: 1963),
    USPresident(firstName: "Dwight",    lastName: "Eisenhowser",    startYear: 1953, endYear: 1961),
    USPresident(firstName: "Andrew",    lastName: "Jackson",        startYear: 1865, endYear: 1869),
    USPresident(firstName: "George",    lastName: "Washington",     startYear: 1789, endYear: 1796),
]

let desiredYears = [1953]
let result = allPresidents.filter { president in
    desiredYears.contains(where:) { president.yearsInOffice.contains($0) }
}
print("\n\nPresident in 1953 was:  = \(result)\n\n")
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood but the question states the filter is to be based on the `startYear`. This solution is based on `yearsInOffice`.

Comment: I was going by the print statement: "President in 1953 was ..."

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it does not exactly solve this question. I will, however, use this solution at another time. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Codable` adds almost no value to your problem, as your query runs on the already decoded objects, and `Codable` helps with the transition from raw data to instances of your struct.

Also, having `searchFor` as an array only complicates things if you want to find out who was president in a certain year. I'd recommend going back to a simple year.

Now, getting to the chase, you can use the `first(where:)` method to find out the first element from a list that matches a given query.

```
let searchFor = 1953
let result = allPresidents.first(where: { $0.startYear...$0.endYear ~= searchFor })
print("\n\n President in \(searchFor) was \(result)\n\n")
```

Just a note that `first(where:)` returns an optional, so you might need to unwrap the value if you want to pass it forward.

Comment: Your explanation is right on! I used Codable because this problem is an excerpt from a larger problem where I downloaded JSON from a Web server. Thank you for your time, and explanation, which does produce the desired result.